# Folders to ignore on subversion commit

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, svn

Which folders may I not commit to subversion server?

I'm talking about an standard asp.net web application in Visual Studio 2.008. I think the bin folder because it's files are regenerated, is there any other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We put this string as the svn:ignore property on all our projects:

```
*.pdb  
*.exe  
*.dll  
debug/*  
release/*  
*.user  
*.suo  
obj/*  
bin/*  
obj  
bin  
VSMacros80
```

Comment: Doesn't the *.dll remove your dependencies? i.e. the lib folder if that's where you store them

Comment: keep in mind that SVN will allow you to commit ignored files if they're already under version control.  It just won't list the unversioned ones that are ignored.  You can thus add any dll files you need and it will version them normally.

Comment: First: My dependencies that I have source code for, is built when the parent project is built.

If we use 3rd party assemblies, these are kept, as rmeador points out SVN will allow you to commit ignored filetypes if they're already under version control. So you can always add an ignored file.

Comment: Note, sometimes ignoring "bin" is not the same as "Bin". I suggest ignoring the uppercase version of those directories as well..

Comment: Can't you do something like [Bb]in to ignore both lower- and uppercase?

Answer (score 3):

For any C# project I would recommend to ignore the following files/directories:

**Visual Studio files to ignore**

- `*.pdb` — Files that hold states information when debugging.
- `*.exe` — Executable binaries.
- `*.dll` — Library binaries.
- `debug/*` — Folder used by Visual Studio to store a lot of debugging information
- `release/*` — Folder used by Visual Studio to store binary releases.
- `*.user` — Configuration per user.
- `*.suo` — Options settings per user stored in binary format.
- `obj` — Folder used by Visual Studio to store binary objects used while debugging.
- `bin` — Folder used by Visual Studio to store compiled objects.
- `VSMacros80` — Folder used by Visual Studio to store macros.

**Other files to ignore**

- `packages` — Folder used for NuGet references.
- `*.log` — In case of having logs written in the source folder (*this should not happen*).

**Note:** Remember to add these pattern to be ignored recursively.

---

**Extra (copy-n-paste)**

```
*.pdb  
*.exe  
*.dll  
debug/*  
release/*  
*.user  
*.suo
obj  
bin  
VSMacros80
packages
*.log
```

Answer (score 1):

obj is another one, as they're debug symbols built during compilation.